# How to remove set of matching characters at the end of the string in a shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, ksh

I want to remove set of matching characters at the end of the string in a shell script. It should work in all the linux flavours, ideally with out using tools like sed,awk.
I found some examples on web but all of them are about removing a single character type.

Below is a set of examples which shows what I am trying to achieve.
Please help.

```
1. Input : test_-
   Output: test  

2. Input: test-_-
   Output: test

3. Input: test1__-
   Output: test1
```

I want to remove the all the "hyphen" and "underscore" characters from the end of the string.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, Thank you for your quick response. I don't have much experience in writing shell scripts. I need to run the command in a script and assign the output to a variable. could you please give complete command using one of the examples I have given.

Comment: Sorry the way this site works is that first you need to provide some code in your question (even if it doesn't work). You will get much more help.

Comment: @anubhava That will remove all `-`s and `_`s, not just at the end.

Comment: `with out using tools like sed,awk`.  Why the extra complexity?  That is what these tools are made for.

Comment: @Nic3500 No extra complexity is involved by using shell here. The solution to this problem is a short one-liner, even in POSIX shell.

Comment: Care to share with the rest of the class :)

Comment: `${s%"${s##*[^_-]}"}` where `s` is the variable holding the string.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin `^` is not specified by POSIX AFAIK, so `${s%"${s##*[!_-]}"}`

Comment: @rowboat That appears to be correct. The `^` must be replaced by the `!` in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are tagging this *zsh*:

Assuming that your string is stored in a variable `input`, you can do a

```
 if [[ $input =~ ^((.*[^-_])) ]]
 then
   output=$MATCH
 fi
```

The `.*` does a greedy match, which guarantees that the last character is neither a dash nor a hyphen.

In bash, this works similar, only that you have to set

```
output=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Answer (score -1):

Supposing your data is in a file, like

```
test_-
test-_-
test1__-
```

with grep

```
grep -oP '[a-z]*[0-9]*' data.txt
```

Comment: The user says that the data are at the end of a _string_, which most likely means that  it is in a variable, not in a file.

Comment: The OP also says "It should work in all the linux flavours, **ideally with out using tools like sed,awk**" (emphasize mine)